# How to check the ip/hostname of remote machines that has ever ssh into my local Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

For some reason, I need to remote access Machine A. However, I do not know its hostname and IP address. What I know is that, I have, from Machine A, used SSH to access another Machine B, and also used scp on Machine A to copy files from Machine B. Now, I have access to Machine B. Is there a way to know the hostname or IP address of Machine A?

Comment: If you want to check for/monitor fails, setup fail2ban so people who have to many failed bans are blocked for a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean successfully logons (otherwise just view via all `/var/log/auth.log*`), you can use the `last` command.  For historical records, you will need to parse the backup files of `/var/log/wtmp`.

Hope this helps.